# How can I test and/or disable caching in RSpec benchmark tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, benchmarking

Trying to benchmark page load time for my rails app -- first pass is EXTREMELY slow and subsequent page loads are quite speedy. My first thought was that this might be due to effective caching but I'm getting the same spread even if I clear the cache between test runs.

```
feature "program index view", benchmarks: true do
  before(:each) do
    Rails.cache.clear
    puts "clearing"
  end

  scenario "loads slow first time" do
    seed_db

    time = Benchmark.realtime { visit programs_path as: @learner }

    puts "first time took #{time}"

    expect(true).to be_truthy
  end

  scenario "loads fast second time" do
    seed_db

    time = Benchmark.realtime { visit programs_path as: @learner }

    puts "second time took #{time}"

    expect(true).to be_truthy
  end


  def seed_db
    puts "starting db seed"
    # create a TON of objects here
    puts "finished db seeding"
  end
end
```

First pass is around 25 seconds! Second time it's 0.28 seconds!

This mirrors what I'm seeing in production, wherein we get occasional, epically slow response times, especially after app has been inactive or recently restarted. Then after the first ping, it's pretty snappy for a while. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can disable caching entirely in your /environments/test.rb add `config.cache_store = :null_store`

Comment: Thanks -- but hoping not to disable caching entirely. In fact my preference would be to clearly test and compare initial response time vs subsequent (post cache) response times, to ensure that caching is working but that first time page loads are still reasonable.

Comment: Guess my question is -- can I be sure sure that the gains are tied to caching?  Or, given that I've disabled caching and am still seeing the gains, is there something else I'm missing?